# JQuery Validation on file input on IE8

Tags: jquery, validation, internet-explorer-8

I have some custom validation on a file input type which looks like the following

```
var fileOne = $("#fileOne").val();

if(fileOne.length == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('error');
    errors.push("- Please upload a document");
} else if($("#fileOne")[0].files[0].size > 2097152) {
    errors.push("- Please upload a file smaller than 2MB");
} else if(  $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/bmp' &&
    $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/jpeg' &&
    $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'image/pjpeg' &&
    $("#fileOne")[0].files[0].type != 'application/pdf') {
    errors.push("- Please upload one of the valid document types");
}
```

Now without any validation, the file gets uploaded fine (in IE8) and added to my document.  With the above validation in place however, IE8 seems to throw an error

> Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

pointing to the two else if's above.  If I ignore the error and let the form process, the file is not added to my document.

So why would IE8 complain about the above code?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks